# create distribution from a list and generate random numbers which follow that distribution in Python

Tags: python, random, distribution

Lets say I have a list of numbers (all numbers are within 0.5 to 1.5 in this particular example and of course it is a discrete set ).

```
my_list=  [0.564, 1.058, 0.779, 1.281, 0.656, 0.863, 0.958, 1.146, 0.742, 1.139, 0.957, 0.548, 0.572, 1.204, 0.868, 0.57, 1.456, 0.586, 0.718, 0.966, 0.625, 0.951, 0.766, 1.458, 0.83, 1.25, 0.7, 1.334, 1.015, 1.43, 1.376, 0.942, 1.252, 1.441, 0.795, 1.25, 0.851, 1.383, 0.969, 0.629, 1.008, 0.729, 0.841, 0.619, 0.63, 1.189, 0.514, 0.899, 0.807, 0.63, 1.101, 0.528, 1.385, 0.838, 0.538, 1.364, 0.702, 1.129, 0.639, 0.557, 1.28, 0.664, 1.021, 1.43, 0.792, 1.229, 0.837, 1.183, 0.54, 0.831, 1.279, 1.385, 1.377, 0.827, 1.32, 0.537, 1.19, 1.446, 1.222, 0.762, 1.302, 0.626, 1.352, 1.316, 1.286, 1.239, 1.027, 1.198, 0.961, 0.515, 0.989, 0.979, 1.123, 0.889, 1.484, 0.734, 0.718, 0.758, 0.782, 1.163, 0.579, 0.744, 0.711, 1.13, 0.598, 0.913, 1.305, 0.684, 1.108, 1.373, 0.945, 0.837, 1.129, 1.005, 1.447, 1.393, 1.493, 1.262, 0.73, 1.232, 0.838, 1.319, 0.971, 1.234, 0.738, 1.418, 1.397, 0.927, 1.309, 0.784, 1.232, 1.454, 1.387, 0.851, 1.132, 0.958, 1.467, 1.41, 1.359, 0.529, 1.139, 1.438, 0.672, 0.756, 1.356, 0.736, 1.436, 1.414, 0.921, 0.669, 1.21, 1.041, 0.597, 0.541, 1.162, 1.292, 0.538, 1.011, 0.828, 1.356, 0.897, 0.831, 1.018, 1.412, 1.363, 1.371, 1.231, 1.278, 0.564, 1.134, 1.324, 0.593, 1.307, 0.66, 1.376, 1.469, 1.315, 0.959, 1.099, 1.313, 1.032, 1.128, 1.175, 0.64, 0.581, 1.09, 0.934, 0.698, 1.272]
```

I can make a histogram distribution plot from it as

```
hist(my_list, bins=20, range=[0.5,1.5])
show()
```

which produces [image]

Now, I want to create another list of random numbers (lets say this new list consists of 100 numbers) that will follow the same distribution (not sure how to link a discrete set in to a continuous distribution !!! ) as the old list ( my_list ) , so if I plot the histogram distribution from the new list, it will essentially produce the same histogram distribution.

Is there any way to do so in Python 2.7 ? I appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: You can do a KDE approximation of your distribution with `approx_dist = scipy.stats.kde.gaussian_kde(my_list)`, then sample from it using `approx_dist.resample(n)`. It depends on exactly how you want you approximation to work, so maybe you should read up on KDE and see if that meets your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to "bucket up" the range of interest, and of course you can do it with tools from `scipy` &c, but for the sake of understanding what's going on a little Python version might help - with no optimizations, for ease of understanding:

```
import collections

def buckets(discrete_set, amin=None, amax=None, bucket_size=None):
    if amin is None: amin=min(discrete_set)
    if amax is None: amax=min(discrete_set)
    if bucket_size is None: bucket_size = (amax-amin)/20
    def to_bucket(sample):
        if not (amin <= sample <= amax): return None  # no bucket fits
        return int((sample - amin) // bucket_size)
    b = collections.Counter(to_bucket(s)
            for s in discrete_set if to_bucket(s) is not None)
    return amin, amax, bucket_size, b
```

So, now you have a `Counter` (essentially a `dict`) mapping each bucket from 0 up to its count as observed in the discrete set.

Next, you'll want to generate a random sample matching the bucket distribution measured by calling `buckets(discrete_set)`.  A Counter's `elements` method can help, but you need a list for `random.sample`...:

```
mi, ma, bs, bks = buckets(discrete_set) 
buckelems = list(bks.elements())
```

(this may waste a lot of space, but you can optimize it later, separately from this understanding-focused overview:-).

Now it's easy to get an N-sized sample, e.g:

```
def makesample(N, buckelems, mi, ma, bs):
    s = []
    for _ in range(N):
        buck = random.choice(buckelems)
        x = random.uniform(mi+buck*bs, mi+(buck+1)*bs)
        s.append(x)
    return s
```

Here I'm assuming the buckets are fine-grained enough that it's OK to use a uniform distribution within each bucket.

Now, optimizing this is of course interesting -- `buckelems` will have as many items as originally were in `discrete_set`, and if that imposes an excessive load on memory, cumulative distributions can be built and used instead.

Or, one could bypass the `Counter` altogether, and just "round" each item in the discrete set to its bucket's lower bound, if memory's OK but one wants more speed.  Or, one could leave `discrete_set` alone and `random.choice` within it before "perturbing" the chosen value (in different ways depending on the constraints of the exact problem).  No end of fun...!-)

Comment: awesome ! no doubt the perfect answer! but let me ask another thing, do you think there is any other faster way to do so, bcoz, my actual problem has more that 50 such independent distributions and the whole procedure is under an optimization so goes through many iterations.

Comment: "perfect answer" and not even one upvote?!  Yes there are optimizations possible (see my last 2 paragraphs) where you avoid the bucketed histograms, but I'm sure not gonna spend more time on this until bribed with an upvote!-)

Comment: haha, why do you even worry about an upvote while you know for sure that I am not only going to upvote but also going to accept your answer, as i said, 'perfect answer'. i was just taking sometime understanding the whole code you wrote :-)

Comment: "What, me worry?" (A.N:-).  Was just hinting.  BTW, if you edit your Q (or open another) with more details, I'll be glad to show code for a likely more optimized approach (if you don't need histograms but just "simulated samples" with the same distribution; esp. if you need many simulated samples from just one starting discrete set; etc, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Don't read too much into valleys and peaks of histograms with low sample sizes when you're trying to do distribution fitting.

I performed a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test on your data to test the hypothesis that they come from a Uniform(0.5,1.5) distribution, and failed to reject.  Consequently, you can generate any size sample you want of Uniform(0.5,1.5)'s.

Given your statement that the underlying distribution is continuous, I think that a distribution-fitting approach is better than a histogram/bucket-based approach.

Comment: interesting (!!!) as my original goal (though I did not mention in the question) is to create new list which is generated from the old list according to the old distribution and do the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to check how close is the new distribution to the old distribution.  can you give an example of how to write python code in 'distribution-fitting approach' that you mentioned?

Comment: and keep repeating the process (in a loop) to get the closest most distribution as the original/old distribution one (by optimization)